# Login From javascript Http website to a Https Api server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

First, sorry for my bad English, im french.

I wish to offer my customers a javascript file to connect to my website without the need of a server-side like asp or php and/or ssl certificate.

I use mvc 5 with WebApi 2.0. OAuth 2.0 is configured and work with an WPF Application which makes an api call to my website.

In my Customer Website Javascript, the user may be allowed to login/register to my website without leaving the customer's website. So the customer has it's own website which use data from my website.

All the connections to my website is https, but the Customer Website will be in http or https. Each Customer's Website will have a key like client_id in OAUTH2.

I spent all day reading how to do this, but I cannot find what the best for my needs is.

What is the closet solution I have found is this page for WebApi authentication: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

and this to allow cross origin requests: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

but this, I think, will required the client to have an ssl certificate to encrypt the data.

if some one can point me to the right direction, this will make my day :)

Thank you!

Comment: i have find a way to do it, but i have only tested it in http, not in https. I will have to try it and check with fiddler if data is encrypted.

In the sample for WebApi authentication, they dont use a key, they just specify "self" in code but not in javascript.
I can pass it as a param in the ajax data ... i'm looking for this now ...